# How to order a list of lists based on number of elements within the inner list? - python

Tags: python, list, sorting

For example if I have:

```
a = [[[5,4,3,2],[6,7,8,9]], [[1,2,3],[1,2,7]], [[2,2], [0,4]], [[5,6,7,1],[9,0,3,4]]]
```

I want to sort this is descending order where ties don't really matter. I figured I would try to access the length of the first index of each inner list such as `a[0][0] = 4` and compare that length against the lengths of the first index of the other inner lists, but I'm not really sure how to sort from there.

I would like to output:

```
[[[5,4,3,2],[6,7,8,9]], [[5,6,7,1],[9,0,3,4]], [[1,2,3],[1,2,7]], [[2,2],[0,4]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort by the `len` of the `[0]` element of each sublist.

```
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda i: len(i[0]), reverse=True)
[[[5, 4, 3, 2], [6, 7, 8, 9]], [[5, 6, 7, 1], [9, 0, 3, 4]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 7]], [[2, 2], [0, 4]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a list of lists ... it's a list of lists of lists! Here's the total length of a list of lists:

```
def total_length(list_of_lists):
    return sum(len(l) for l in list_of_lists)
```

And here's how to use that to sort the top-level lists:

```
result = sorted(a, key=total_length, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one liner:

```
a.sort(key = lambda li: len(li[0]), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted()` with a custom key:

```
a = [[[5,4,3,2],[6,7,8,9]], [[1,2,3],[1,2,7]], [[2,2], [0,4]], [[5,6,7,1],[9,0,3,4]]]
print(sorted(a,key=lambda l: len([s for i in l for s in i]),reverse=True))
```

Output:

```
[[[5, 4, 3, 2], [6, 7, 8, 9]], [[5, 6, 7, 1], [9, 0, 3, 4]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 7]], [[2, 2], [0, 4]]]
```